# In NixOS, how to add a user to the sudoers file?

Tags: nixos

I installed and am trying to get started with NixOS, and am trying to add my user to the sudoers file.

So that I'm not running all my commands as root I created a user following [Chapter 7. User Management](https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/#sec-user-management) of the NixOS manual. That is, I ran

```
# useradd -m matthew
# su - matthew -c "true"
# passwd matthew
Enter new UNIX password: ***
Retype new UNIX password: ***
```

And also I added

```
users.extraUsers.matthew = {
    isNormalUser = true;
    home = "/home/matthew";
    extragroups = [ "wheel" "networkmanager" ];
}
```

to `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`. But still I am not able to run `sudo` as `matthew`.
For example, when I try to open sudo's man page with sudo, I get the `matthew is not in the sudoers file` error.

```
$ sudo man sudo
[sudo] password for matthew:
matthew is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.
```

Then I tried following [advice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18224/how-to-add-a-user-to-sudoers-file) on how to add a user to the sudoers file in other distributions, namely editing with `$ visudo`. But when I run that, nixos tells me not to edit that file. That is, running

```
$ visudo
```

opens `/etc/sudoers.tmp` with first line reading

```
# Don't edit this file. Set the NixOS option ‘security.sudo.configFile’ instead.
```

**How do I set the NixOS option ‘security.sudo.configFile’?**

Comment: Breadcrumb: https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/#sec-user-management

Comment: @JeffSchaller thanks for the comment; I've tried following the instructions on that page. That is, I added the 'users.extraUsers.matthew' block to my '/etc/nixos/configuration.nix' and also ran 'useradd -m matthew' and 'su - alice -c "true"', and set password and all. Still getting the 'not in sudoers file' error.

Comment: It's odd that this doesn't work. I happen to be working with a fresh NixOS install today, and adding `"wheel"` to `extraGroups` worked just fine. Note that it's `extraGroups` and not `extragroups`.

Answer (score 9):

Adding a user to the `wheel` group should be sufficient to gain sudo privileges.

```
users.extraUsers.matthew = {
    isNormalUser = true;
    home = "/home/matthew";
    extraGroups = [ "wheel" ];
}
```

**After** you've added a user to a new linux group, you need to **logout and login those users**, for those changes to take effect (new group).

Edit: as suggests a comment under the question above, it should be `extraGroups` not `extragroups`.

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, adding the user with `useradd` and editing `users.extraUsers` is redundant. I've never bothered with `useradd` on NixOS.

As for the sudo configuration, what you do is set `security.sudo.configFile` to a string containing what you'd normally put into sudoers:

```
security.sudo.configFile = ''
   Sudoers config goes here
''
```

Comment: Thank you. I added "security.sudo.configFile = ''%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL''" to /etc/nixos/configuration.nix and that did not work, but then I ran the command "$ usermod -a -G matthew wheel" and that did work.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that in your case, the problem comes from the fact that you created the same user both imperatively (with `useradd`) and declaratively (in `configuration.nix`).

First of all, make sure that you run `nixos-rebuild switch` after each change to `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`. Second, if that is not enough, it is probably that the options that you passed declaratively cannot be used given that the user was already created. In which case, removing the user first and running `nixos-rebuild switch` then should solve the issue.

Comment: Might be needed to log out/in or at least open a new login shell too? In my experience that's often needed for changes that involve group changes.

Comment: Indeed, that's probably the case. On a fast laptop, I would even consider doing `nixos-rebuild boot` followed by `reboot`.

Comment: Thank you @Zimmi48. I was rebooting after each change to /etc/nixos/configuration.nix, but running 'nixos-rebuild switch' is much faster. And also, from the output I was able to identify a syntax error in my .../configuration.nix which seemed to be causing my user to not be added to the wheel group.

Comment: Note that rebooting alone doesn't do any good. It needs to be preceded by `nixos-rebuild boot` or `nixos-rebuild switch`